# how to automatically open .ics file after org-icalendar-export-to-ics?

Tags: org-export, org-agenda, bash, ical

I use `org-icalendar-export-to-ics` to export org-agenda scheduled tasks to iCal format, which works nicely. In my use case, I always select export the "current file" (as opposed to "combine all agenda files").

This has the effect of creating an `.ics` file with a name like `foo.ics`. I then have to go navigate in Finder to go find that file and then open it in iCal.

How can I direct Emacs to `open` or `open-with` that `.ics` file automatically upon `org-icalendar-export-to-ics`? I can't imagine a scenario where I would want to export to an `.ics` file but not go on to open the `.ics` file and import the task into iCal.

Maybe some bash scripting around `org-after-save-iCalendar-file-hook`? The documentation for `org-after-save-iCalendar-file-hook` says "A good way to use this is to tell a desktop calendar application to re-read the iCalendar file," but it doesn't say how to go about telling my desktop calendar to do that.

Comment: How about?  `(defun test-fn (file) (start-process "my-process" nil "open" "-a" "/Applications/iCal.app" file)) (add-hook 'org-after-save-iCalendar-file-hook 'test-fn)`

Comment: @lawlist Thanks! Doesn't work yet. Do we need to specify the file in the hook somehow?

Comment: Can we please clarify the name of the hook -- the hook specified in your question is different than the one I see here:  http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob_plain;f=lisp/ox-icalendar.el;hb=HEAD  In the code that I linked to, the hook is named `org-icalendar-after-save-hook`.  Once we get the name of the hook correct, you can start with a simple test to just generate a message in the `*Messages*` buffer:  `(defun test-fn (file) (message "This is the name of the file:  %s" file)) (add-hook 'org-icalendar-after-save-hook 'test-fn)`  Then, adjust the name of the hook in the first comment.

Comment: @lawlist You were right, that was the problem. I modified a couple other things, this code now works: `(defun org-icalendar-open-ics-file (file) (start-process "org-icalendar-open-ics-file-process" nil "open" "-a" "/Applications/Calendar.app" file)) (add-hook 'org-icalendar-after-save-hook 'org-icalendar-open-ics-file)`

Comment: Yes, newer versions of OSX have renamed `iCal` to `Calendar` -- I'm glad we got it all sorted out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In conjunction with the assistance of the original poster in the comments above, here is the final solution:

```lisp
(defun org-icalendar-open-ics-file (file)
  (start-process "org-icalendar-open-ics-file-process" nil "open" "-a" "/Applications/Calendar.app" file))

(add-hook 'org-icalendar-after-save-hook 'org-icalendar-open-ics-file)
```

Comment: When I use org-icalendar-combine-agenda-files, the created ics should open correct? it is not working on my end. Nothing happens. Just the ics gets created.

Comment: @Adelita -- I don't have access to a modern version of MacOS .. the newest I have is El Capitan on one laptop.  This question/answer is from the year 2016 ... things may have changed on newer versions of the OS and the aspect of org-mode that is related to this issue may also have been updated since then.

Comment: Fair point. thanks for your asnwer.