# Can I automatically export org deadlines and scheduled tasks as an iCal file and import it with another calendar app?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-agenda, calendar, ical

I would like to update Google Calendar / iCal automatically by exporting my org deadlines and scheduled tasks in .ics format, then automatically importing them into a cross-platform calendar app. I have tried the org / Google Calendar integration and been unable to get it to work. Is it possible to use cron jobs or some other method to automate this task?

Update: I have used org-icalendar-export-to-ics to export my org file and then manually imported it into the OSX calendar app, and it then appears in my Google Calendar. I am wondering whether anyone has a way to automate this process. As a first step, I envision running a command from the terminal that launches emacs with an argument that sends the org-icalendar-export-to-ics command. Is that possible? After that, I'll have to set up a way to automatically import the .ics file into either OSX calendar or Google Calendar.

Comment: Please edit your post to show what you've tried so far, and what's not working.

Comment: Done. I am an elisp novice and have been using Emacs for about a year, and have an intermediate knowledge of the command line.

Comment: See this related thread entitled **how to automatically open .ics file after org-icalendar-export-to-ics?**:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28627/how-to-automatically-open-ics-file-after-org-icalendar-export-to-ics/28694#28694

Answer (score 0):

org-gcal may help you, though it skips the step importing ical data into your ical app.

- https://github.com/myuhe/org-gcal.el

Comment: Look for here for melpa version:
https://melpa.org/#/org-gcal